# filter an multidimentional array with more that one condition using array_filter and function

Tags: php, arrays

the following is a multidimensional array; from where i have tried to filter out the list of all sub arrays contents where "level" value is equal to 4 by using 
code (mentioned below); Can some one direct me how to gain the same list with two or more conditions applied to the same code.

Ex `roleid =3 && level = 4 && queryid=59`

```
//array as follows
$Row_Hedder =
Array
(

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => Suman
            [roleid] => 3
            [password] => drf123
            [level] => 3
            [queryid] => 59
            [year] => 2013
            [month] => 1
            [date] => 1
            [pagezone11] => 1
            [visiblename] => Suman
            [em1] => 
            [em2] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [username] => Pranav
            [roleid] => 3
            [password] => drf123
            [level] => 3
            [queryid] => 59
            [year] => 2013
            [month] => 1
            [date] => 1
            [pagezone11] => 2
            [visiblename] => Pranav
            [em1] => 
            [em2] => 
        )
```

the code use to filter is as mentioned below,

```
$filter_val1 = 4;

$filter = function($player) use($filter_val1) { return ($player['level'] == $filter_val1); };

$filtered = array_filter($Row_Hedder, $filter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$filter_rules = array(
  'level' => 4,
  'roleid' => 3,
  'queryid' => 59,
);

$filter = function ($player) use ($filter_rules) {
  foreach ($filter_rules as $rulekey => $rulevalue) {
    if ($player[$rulekey] != $rulevalue) {
      return false; 
    }
  }
  return true; 
};

$filtered = array_filter($Row_Hedder, $filter);
```

The closure checks each rule, it returns true only when all rules are satisfied for that row.